# Django ForeignKey to a model that might not exist

Tags: django

I want to set a foreign key in app1 to a model of app2 that is an optional dependency. To achieve loose coupling, i want app1 to work even if app2 is not installed, with that foreign key simply being deactivated.

Take the following example:

```py
# app1/models.py
class model1(models.Model):
    optional_field = models.ForeignKey(
        "app2.model2", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

If app2 is not installed, the above would raise the following exception:

```
app1.model1: (fields.E307) The field model1.optional_field was 
declared with a lazy reference to 'app2.model2', but app 'app2' 
isn't installed.
```

Is there a way to declare a foreign key that works even if app2 is not installed?

Comment: Well you're on the way! what's the problem? It's important to note that if you want to use `optional_field` in your code, you will need to handle the case where the foreign key is not set, and the field is `None`. You should also handle the case where the related `app2` model may not exist or is not installed.

Comment: @SunderamDubey, but how do I handle the case where app2 is not installed?

Comment: Using Foreign key will create a constraint and thus need the table to exist. If your table is likely not to exist then you cannot use a foreign key. You need a nullable field of the same kind of the expected reference but you cannot use the Foreign key as for sure it requires the table to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You've already got the key requirement, which is for that ForeignKey field to be nullable.

It will get initialized and stored as None/null if you don't assign anything to it. So your code should be fairly clean. If the optional thing is installed, execute code to initialize this field to an app2 model instance  prior to saving new app1 model instances. If not, it should all work without doing anything special.

Likewise, code that processes app1 instances must  test whether `instance.optional_field is None` and do nothing with the linked data if it is.

Only you can tell if this is a good idea. I can't think of any reason that it's a bad one.

Update, in light of comment

There are two ways you can handle the app2 model not existing at all.

What I'd do is to  create an app2 "stub" with nothing in it except the model definition. This will result in the creation of a DB table, but it won't contain any data rows. I don't know what are the implications of later installing the actual app2.

The other would be to not create the field on the app1 model except as part of the installation of app2 (a migration, to create the field and create a column full of nulls). You could then plug the "hole" with a property:

```
class model1(models.Model):

    # defined only if app2 is installed
    #internal_optional_field = models.ForeignKey(
    #    "app2.model2", null=True, blank=True,
    #     on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    #     # DO NOT ACCESS EXCEPT THROUGH optional_field property
    #)  
    
    ...
    @property
    def optional_field(self):
        if not hasattr( self, 'internal_optional_field'):
            return None
        return self.internal_optional_field
    @optional_field.setter( self, value):
        assert hasattr( self, 'internal_optional_field'),
            'Trying to set optional_field, but app2 is not installed'
        self.internal_optional_field = value
```

You might make it `_internal_optional_field` in line with Python conventions, to indicate that it's something which should be left alone by those who don't fully understand it.

Warning - I've never tried this. It ought to work, but do plenty of trial installations and un-installations of the optional model!

Comment: Currently it doesn't work. I have added the exception in the description above to clarify the problem.